Identification of pinout on LED matrix display
First thing first. I'm a beginner at electronics, but I have an LED panel I want to use for a esp32 project. The last couple of days I have been researching for at way to connect to this panel but came up short with a solution.
Spec. on the panel:

64 x 64 RGB pixel
P3.91
250 x 250 mm
Uses a 30 pin header for connection.




As far as I can see it "looks" like an extended HUB320 connector.
There are only 2 of the these connectors on each side.
It seems like most library for Arduino only works with two RGB channels.
If someone can point me in the general direction it would be greatly appreciated.
#Update 1 :
The pin spacing is 2.54mm
I do not a have datasheet, the people i got it from did not have any
knowledge of where one was..
#Update 2 :
I have tried to take the LED panel apart to get a better sense of what it is but researching the id or part number gave no result.
This might just be a custom made connnector setup for the full display, or their way of interfacing with it?





please add a link to the datasheet into your question

What is the exact pitch of those connectors? Please post in-focus, close-up pictures of the connectors.

The pinout looks odd. You've got four RGB sets and then five ABCDE pins. 5 isn't a factor of 16.


#Update 1 : The pin spacing is 2.54mm

Thank you, that was helpful.

Your question isn't spelled out. I assume you're asking "What is this connector?".
Those are standard female PCB socket strips. They mate to standard male PCB pin strips with square posts and a 2.54 mm pitch. Here are many: https://www.digikey.com/short/0918r050
